# How setup different files for Monolog in Silex

Tags: logging, silex, channel, monolog

Subject. I want logging some information in different file, in search a lot examples for Symfony 2, but I use Silex with yaml config. How to set up it?

```
# console logging options
monolog.logfile: '/var/log/daemon.log'
monolog.level: error
monolog.name: 'daemon'
```

My current config

Comment: If you are unable to do this, perhaps you could look at adding delimiters to your log comments and then write a script to extract those comments into other files.

Comment: Just noticed that you can customise Monolog. http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/monolog.html#customization - there you could try adding a new log file. $monolog->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('path/to/your.log', Logger::WARNING))

Answer (score 1):

You need add a extra provider for make this something like this (i just wrote from the scratch so, i will work, i hope) :

config.yaml:

```
monolog.extra.logfile: '/var/log/other.log'
monolog.extra.level: error
```

ExtendedMonologProvider.php:

```
<?php
use Silex\ServiceProviderInterface;
use Silex\Application;

use Silex\Provider\MonologServiceProvider;

class ExtendedMonologProvider implements ServiceProviderInterface {
    public function register(Application $app) {
        $app->register(new MonologServiceProvider());

        $app['monolog.extra.handler'] = function () use ($app) {
            return new StreamHandler($app['monolog.extra.logfile'], $app['monolog.extra.level']);
        };

        $app['monolog'] = $app->share($app->extend('monolog', function($log, $app) {
            $log->pushHandler($app['monolog.extra.handler']);
            return $log;
        }));
    }

    public function boot(Application $app) { }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just extend monolog after register provider and push a new handler, you can use any monolog handler or your custom handler.

```
use Silex\Provider\MonologServiceProvider;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\Logger;

$app->register(new MonologServiceProvider(), [
    'monolog.logfile' => /your/log/path/file.log',
]);

//extend monolog
$app->extend('monolog', function ($monolog, $app) {
    $monolog->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('/your/log/path/other.log', Logger::DEBUG));
    return $monolog;
});
```

Comment: And... How to log into file.log or log into other.log ?